# How select only 1 row with latest date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005. I have two tables with shipments information in the following rows:

> ```
> TABLE1: SHIPMNT_NO
>         SHIPMNT_LN_NO
>         CUSTOMER
>
> TABLE2: SHIPMNT_NO
>         SHIPMNT_LN_NO
>         SHIP_DT
>         QTY
> ```

There are multiple rows in TABLE2 with the same values for SHIPMNT_NO and SHIPMNT_LN_NO, but having different values for the ship dates (SHIP_DT).

> ```
> SHIPMNT_NO   SHIPMNT_LN_NO    SHIPMNT_DT
>  965271         1             2013-02-07 00:00:00.000
>  965271         1             2013-02-12 00:00:00.000
>  965271         1             2013-02-14 00:00:00.000
>  965271         1             2013-02-16 00:00:00.000
>  965271         1             2013-02-18 00:00:00.000
> ```

I need to join the tables together on SHIPMNT_NO and SHIPMNT_LN_NO. But I only need the distinct SHIPMNT_NO and SHIPMNT_LN_NO rows having the most recent date (SHIPMNT_DT).

> ```
> select a.SHIPMNT_NO, a.SHIPMNT_LN_NO, b.QTY
> from TABLE1 a join TABLE2 b on b.SHIPMNT_NO = a.SHIPMNT_NO
>                            and b.SHIPMNT_LN_NO = a.SHIPMNT_LN_NO
> Where?????
> ```

What can I do with a WHERE or JOIN or SUBQUERY?

Hopefully it is clear of what I am trying to accomplish but please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Why, why, why do your column names not have the letter `E`? Do you know how much ***harder*** it is to type `SHIPMNT` than `SHIPMENT`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I bet it's an abbreviation *to save time* - it comes in pair with `_DATE` shortened to `_DT`. I'm sure one must *really* concentrate while typing these names.

Comment: @andr yes, I get it, I just think it's an extremely inconvenient abbreviation. Vowels are useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT a.SHIPMNT_NO, a.SHIPMNT_LN_NO, b.QTY, b.SHIPMNT_DT,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (
        PARTITION BY a.SHIPMNT_NO, a.SHIPMNT_LN_NO
        ORDER BY b.SHIPMNT_DT DESC
      )
   FROM dbo.TABLE1 AS a 
   INNER JOIN dbo.TABLE2 AS b 
   ON b.SHIPMNT_NO = a.SHIPMNT_NO
   AND b.SHIPMNT_LN_NO = a.SHIPMNT_LN_NO
)
SELECT SHIPMNT_NO, SHIPMNT_LN_NO, QTY --, SHIPMNT_DT
FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the row_number() function:

```
select SHIPMNT_NO, SHIPMNT_LN_NO, QTY
from (select a.SHIPMNT_NO, a.SHIPMNT_LN_NO, b.QTY,
             row_number() over (partition by shipmnt_no, shipmnt_ln_no order by shipmnt_dt desc) as seqnum
      from TABLE1 a join TABLE2 b on b.SHIPMNT_NO = a.SHIPMNT_NO
                       and b.SHIPMNT_LN_NO = a.SHIPMNT_LN_NO
    ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential number to rows in a group.  In this case, the group is defined by the shipment description.  The ordering is defined by the shipment_dt, with the most recent getting a value of 1.

If you think you might have ties (two rows with the same date in the same group) *and* you want all of them, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant! The row_number() function with partitioning did the trick! And I learned something new today :)